# Ask Ubuntu seems fundamentally broken for new users

Tags: discussion, community

I came on here to ask a question. While I was here I saw a question I thought I could help with. They had already received some feedback that the question was more than one thing being asked, but to me that made sense to diagnose the issue and rule some things out.

I wrote an answer suggesting some steps that might be taken to fix the issue if it were certain things causing it, and some diagnostic steps to pin down what the issue was.

I then got a comment that my answer was a comment rather than an answer, and a downvote.

I took this onboard and tried to create a comment, only to find I needed 50 reputation in order to do it!

How am I supposed to earn reputation within the community by sharing my knowledge if I'm not allowed to participate in the diagnostic process until I get enough reputation?

Comment: ...but you have over 50 reputation now. So go ahead and comment.

Comment: It is not "fundamentally broken" but designed that way. Once you have been around and active for a while, you will see the benefits to restricting user privileges on the site, I am yet to find one that didn't. Sure, it can feel like a slap in the face when you just want to help out but ultimately these restrictions are the reason you can find good answers and rarely have to deal with spammers or trolls. Without strict rules in place, we would be Yahoo answer in a week and then no one is getting a straight answer.